# Ubuntu server 16.04.1 ubuntu/ubuntu login incorrect

Tags: pi-3, server, ubuntu

I downloaded the ubuntu 16.04.1 server via berryboot on a raspberry pi 3 and booted it up. The default login is ubuntu/ubuntu but whenever I try this I get "Incorrect login". Any help?

Comment: I don't know **what** BerryBoot does, but this is an old version of the server. **WHY** would anyone want to use BerryBoot for a server?

Comment: Because I am running 3 OSes on my Pi. Arch, Ubuntu Mate and this server. I didn't find a way to do this with NOOBS or as easy with an other method. @Milliways

Comment: I can understand multi booting of OS, but a server that isn't there seems futile.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. :/ @Milliways

Comment: visit this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Comment: The one you linked me is actually the one I'm copying to a USB drive to try now. Thanks for the hint though. @Hamed

Comment: I'm using this: ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf + raspi3
And when I start for the first time I ask for login, I put ubuntu / ubuntu and it asks me to write the new password. Once typed, it shows me the login again but ignores the new password. If I start again with ubuntu / ubuntu it asks me for the new password ...

Comment: I do not know the reason, but I connected by SSH from another PC and if I could do the password change without any problems.

Comment: If you have additional information, edit and add it to the question and not in comments,

Comment: The point of using berryboot is having multiple OSes.. This makes me have one.

Answer (score 1):

When you run into this problem, just allow your device to complete the first boot. There may be still a background process being busy executing cloud-init and the Ubuntu user hasn't been created yet.

For, just trying again after more wait time fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can sometimes use a default login of:

login name:  ubuntu

password blank

But usually you won't see that unless running from a LiveCD.

Full installations ask you to set up a user.

Then while logged in as that user you can set the root password:

```
sudo passwd root
```